# Show detail section under Footer Section

Tags: crystal-reports

I am using Crystal Reports. Is it possible in crystal that if i want to print details section under footer section. I have all the calculation at footer level and after that i want display all details records.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can but you will need to create a sub-report that has all the details you'd like to display and then import/embed the additional report in the footer.

Comment: Actually database file is very big i can't do with subrpt it will be very slow... is there any other way?

Comment: unfortunately no, details can only go in the "details" section of a report. Have you tried it as a subreport? In the past crystal has been decent when dealing with large sets of data. And remember whether the data is in the main report or a subreport the user still needs to load it all.